# Where can I get information about relationships among probability distributions in statistics?

Tags: distributions, references

I'm interested in relationships among distributions.
Like 'Sum of exponential random variables is a gamma random variable. Certain conditional distribution is another distribution etc.'
I searched wikipedia and google but there are just summaries of them, not specifically proved or explained.
I want to know about distribution's relationships and detailed proof or explanation. 
Either web sites or books would be OK.

Comment: What about Page 47 of http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/2008amstat.pdf ?

Comment: with an almost interactive version at http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/UDR.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i already read that and there are no specific explanation or proofs... i can't fully understand relationships among distributions by given summaries... so sad.

Comment: Related: [Comprehensive list of distributions?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/110235/22228); [Reference with distributions with various properties](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26073/22228)

Answer (score 10):

Those books are massive references on all connections between distributions:

> N.L. Johnson, S. Kotz, & N. Balakrishnan (1994) [Continuous Univariate
>   Distributions](http://amzn.to/2cX4DqQ), Vol. 1. J. Wiley
>
> N.L. Johnson, S. Kotz, & N. Balakrishnan (1995) [Continuous Univariate
>   Distributions](http://amzn.to/2ca4y5Q), Vol. 2. J. Wiley
>
> N.L. Johnson, S. Kotz, & A.W. Kemp (1993) [Univariate Discrete
>   Distributions](http://amzn.to/2csthQ0). J. Wiley

that cover all the links found on [the Wikipedia graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationships_among_probability_distributions). If not *all* possible relationships, of course!

Answer (score 7):

Check the following papers:

> Leemis, L. M. (1986). [Relationships among common univariate
>   distributions.](http://www.mat.ufrgs.br/~viali/exatas/material/textos/Leemis-1986.pdf) The American Statistician, 40(2), 143-146.
>
> Leemis, L. M., & McQueston, J. T. (2008). [Univariate distribution
>   relationships.](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/2008amstat.pdf) The American Statistician, 62(1), 45-53.

You can find such information also in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions) articles about probability distributions since in most cases they have *Related distributions* section that describes such relations.